# Query inherited models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have 3 Models:

```
Actor(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
type = models.Charfield(max_length=20)

Organisation(Actor):
name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
actor = models.OneToOneField(Actor, on_delete=Models.CASCADE)
parent_organisation = models.ForeignKey(Actor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin,Actor):
name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
member_of = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am basically trying to get all users within an organisation:
User and Organisation share a common named id - Actor and Inherit from this class.

I have tried:

```
user_list = CustomerUser.objects.filter(parent__parent__id=request.session['organisation']
```

and

```
user_list = Organisation.objects.filter(parent__parent_user_organisation=request.session[''organisation']
```

and

```
user_list = Actor.objects.filter(parent__parent__user_organisation__in=request.session['organisation'])
```

although I would like to try and keep all queries on the actor model if possible. Eventually, id like to get all users within a multi-tiered organisation structure although for now, I'm happy to get just users based on Organisation_parent rather than ----- Organisation_parent_Organisation_parent etc...

I have changed my model structure to inherited to try and make queries easier but not having much luck.

The full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2348, in to_python
return uuid.UUID(**{input_form: value})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/uuid.py", line 171, in __init__
raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')

During handling of the above exception (badly formed hexadecimal UUID string), another exception occurred:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/usr/src/app/administration/views.py", line 133, in user_list
    user_list = Actor.objects.filter(parent__parent__user_organisation__in=request.session['organisation']) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1311, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 59, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 59, in <listcomp>
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 945, in get_prep_value
    return self.target_field.get_prep_value(value)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2332, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2350, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(

Exception Type: ValidationError at /administration/administration/user/list Exception Value: ['“4” is not a valid UUID.']
```